# how to display value from xmpp in Listview android application

Tags: android

The below will display the buddyList in textview. How can i display the same output in ListView Android application.

Code snippet:

```
    public void displayBuddyList() {
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
        for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
            String buddys;
            {

                TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                // // buddys = textview.getText() + r.getName();
                textview.setText("" + entries); // displays buddy list
}  

        }
    }
```

Please guide me how can i do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know is to have your buddyList stored in array temporarily as follows

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.buddyListView, buddyList)); //buddyListView is your xml file where you will display the list.
       ListView list=getListView();
   list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });
   }



  static final String[] buddyList=new String[]{
    "buddy1", "buddy2", "buddy3"....."buddyN"
};
```